# Fedora installation problems

Tags: fedora, usb, system-installation

I want to install Fedora on my laptop.
I tried many things, but they did not work.

1. I bought a DVD of Fedora 20 online, but it stops between the installation process says there is bug in the DVD. But sometimes when the check the disk then it shows OK, sometimes not.
2. I downloaded Fedora 20 ISO image – it's somewhat over 4 GB – and made my USB bootable using `unetbootin` and "Fedora Live USB Creator". It sometimes stops at the same position where the DVD stops during installation process.

When installation starts, it reports two or three I/O errors
as the process starts then it says anaconda loading. I think that is normal, but after that when it is the time for installation process it keeps showing black screen – but I am able to move the mouse around on my screen.

What is "Fedora Live USB Creator"? Why is its name so confusing live – does it make only live USBs, or does it also create media that can be used to do a full install?

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to download Fedora 22 Workstation installer from Fedora's site (https://getfedora.org/) and run it.  Fedora 20 is a couple of years old and while it is certainly still usable, they have made improvements.

As for the live usb creator, if my memory serves that creates an installable version on a usb device.  I used it once a long time ago on a thumb drive.  The version is meant to be installed on another device, usually a hard drive.

If you want a full, running version of Fedora on a thumb drive you can use the same installer you would use for a hard drive and direct it to the thumb drive (provided it has enough space, of course).  I have such a system that I take to my work, which is a windows environment.  I simply boot from the thumb drive and I'm in Fedora rather than Windows.  If I need Windows for any reason I simply boot from the work computer's hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

As BrianM already explained, you should use the newest version of Fedora and the standart Workstation image. However, follow the instructions from the [Fedora Documentation](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/22/html/Installation_Guide/sect-preparing-boot-media.html). The instructions how to verify the image with a hashsum are also important to avoid a corrupt image.